# How do I get round the hanging bug in kubectl when aws credentials are expired?

Tags: kubectl

If the AWS credentials are expired, `aws ec2 ... etc` will exit immediately with `An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Request has expired.`.

However, `kubectl exec` will hang for 2 minutes before exiting with
`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp <some ip address>:443: i/o timeout`.

Is there a workaround to get `kubectl` to exit immediately instead of hanging for 2 minutes?

Comment: Do you mean AWS credentials or Kubernetes credentials? Did you try to use `ctrl+c` or `--request-timeout` parameter from [Kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/)

Comment: Could you please increase kubectl verbosity to -v 10 to check the exact request that causes the problem? Knowing cluster details, config content and kubernetes versions could be also helpful for investigation. Please redact all private data like keys or IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comment. When you want to exit from `kubectl commands` you can just use `ctrl+c` same as in the console.

If you would like to use more Kubernetes way, you can use `kubectl` with flag `--request-timeout`. More details you can find in [Kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/).

> --request-timeout string     Default: "0"
>
> The length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Non-zero values should contain a corresponding time unit (e.g. 1s, 2m, 3h). A value of zero means don't timeout requests.